# Is it safe to put pots and pans with hard plastic handles on the bottom rack of the dishwasher?

Tags: kitchens, safety, appliances

I have a Whirlpool dishwasher I bought in 2014. It works fine. But where should I put pots and pans with hard plastic handles when I load the dishwasher? I want to put them on the bottom rack, but I wonder if even hard plastic handles might melt from the dryer element at the bottom. Other than the handles, these [image]pots and pans are otherwise made of metal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because “Operation of major appliances or questions regarding small appliances” is specifically listed as off-topic in the help center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The temperature encountered by these handles when used on a gas stove exceeds the temperature of the air anywhere inside a dishwasher even when set on "heated dry", so if they survive the cooking then they will survive the washing.

However -- do not allow any materials to come into direct contact with the heater element.

Answer (score 1):

Ours go in there all the time.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you are fine with placing that in the bottom rack as long as you don't force the plastic handles down under the rack to come in contact with the heating element. That will take some serious effort - so I don't think you will do that.

I can tell you I have had plastic forks, plastic spoons and plastic bowls , and plastic plates in the bottom rack with my washer on HEATED Dry.  I can't count the number of times I have washed them with heated dry but I can tell I wash dishes every day.

True Silverware might have certain disclaimers about washing in the dish washer - so pay attention to that.